# Automatic type generation

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I've created a function in a PL/SQL package that uses a custom type defined as table of numbers. I use an object of this type in an SQL query with the SELECT COLUMN_VALUE instruction like this :

The type definition in the package:

```
type T_IDS is table of my_table.col_id%type;
```

The query inside a procedure in the package body:

```
l_ids_list T_IDS ;
begin
select col_ids bulk collect into T_IDS from my_table;
select sum(t.rec_value) into total_value 
          from my_table t where t.col_id in (
            select column_value from Table(l_ids_list) );
```

Everything works fine and when I compile this code, I can see a new type generated under my schema_name/type section.

Once I installed this on test environment, it fails the compilation with the errors :

> Error: PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
>   Error: PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table
>   item

Database versions (local and test) are exactly the same, 11g. Is there a way to activate such a generation on the DBMS?

exemple to reproduce :

```
create table my_table (
col_id number,
rec_value number
);

insert into my_table (col_id, rec_value) values (1,100);
insert into my_table (col_id, rec_value) values (2,200);
insert into my_table (col_id, rec_value) values (3,300);
insert into my_table (col_id, rec_value) values (4,400);

commit;
```

package creation :

```
create or replace package test_pck as

type T_IDS is table of my_table.col_id%type;

procedure test_list;

end test_pck;
/

create or replace
package body test_pck as

procedure test_list is
  l_ids_list T_IDS ;
  total_value number;
begin
  select col_id bulk collect into l_ids_list from my_table;
  select sum(t.rec_value) into total_value 
            from my_table t where t.col_id in (
              select column_value from Table(l_ids_list) );
end test_list;
end test_pck;
/
```

Comment: you mean both databases are 11.2 ie select * from v$version is the same? did you compile this on test or it was created by export/import from Dev?

Comment: After checking different versions, the one that doesn't compile is a version 11.2.0.3 where the one that compiles is a version 11.2.0.1. The source is compiled directly on the DB and not installed with an export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing is wrong. you should be creating SQL types and not using pl/sql types to access the `TABLE` function.

now as to WHY it actually sorta worked in your Dev env.

The silent pl/sql table creation is intended for pipelined functions and has been around for a while, but you're using this in a non-pipelined function and as such THIS SHOULD FAIL. In 11g release 1 (11.1.0.7 to be precise) though, a bug means that it actually compiles. If you actually tried to run it though you would get an error:

```
SQL> create package body foo
  2  as
  3
  4    procedure test
  5     is
  6             l_ids_list T_IDS ;
  7             total_value number;
  8     begin
  9             select col_id bulk collect into l_ids_list from my_table;
 10             select sum(t.rec_value) into total_value
 11               from my_table t
 12              where t.col_id in (select column_value from Table(l_ids_list));
 13     end;
 14  end;
 15  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec foo.test;
BEGIN foo.test; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete
ORA-06512: at "TEST.FOO", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

now, Oracle FIXED this buggy behaviour in 11.2.0.3. now the error is thrown at compile time:

```
SQL> create package body foo
  2  as
  3
  4    procedure test
  5     is
  6             l_ids_list T_IDS ;
  7             total_value number;
  8     begin
  9             select col_id bulk collect into l_ids_list from my_table;
 10             select sum(t.rec_value) into total_value
 11               from my_table t
 12              where t.col_id in (select column_value from Table(l_ids_list));
 13     end;
 14  end;
 15  /

Warning: Package Body created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE BODY FOO:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
10/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/48    PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table
         item

12/54    PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

in short, create an SQL type with `create type` and use that instead:

```
SQL> create type T_IDS as table of number;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create package body foo
  2  as
  3
  4    procedure test
  5     is
  6             l_ids_list T_IDS ;
  7             total_value number;
  8     begin
  9             select col_id bulk collect into l_ids_list from my_table;
 10             select sum(t.rec_value) into total_value
 11               from my_table t
 12              where t.col_id in (select column_value from Table(l_ids_list));
 13     end;
 14  end;
 15  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec foo.test

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Comment: Yes indeed, the SQL type solved the compilation problem. but what I didn't understand is that the 11.2.0.1 version generated a global type (what you called SQL type) with the same structure as my PL/SQL type but not the 11.2.0.3 which got me to think about a configuration issue. Thank you again

Comment: @HADDARMohamed no its not a configuration issue. like i said, it was a BUG in 11.1.0.7-11.2.0.2 that meant the type was generated and the compilation succeeded. both should not have happened. if you have Oracle support access, look up "Bug 9383293 - A PL/SQL table type variable used in a SQL statement within a PL/SQL block fails at runtime instead of compile time [ID 9383293.8]"